# validating user session in php

Tags: php

I am creating few pages (including login page) which should only be accessible by a sysadmin.

In login.php after the user's credentials have been verified. I set a session variable like so:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", $values['uname'], $values['password']) or 
die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("somedb") or die (mysql_error());

session_start();
$_SESSION['level'] = 'admin';
header('Location: /admin/index.php');
```

And then in the index.php page I am doing the following:

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['level'] !== 'admin'){
    header("location:../admin/login.php");
}
?>
```

But it does not seem to work.  Everytime I am being redirected to login.php  (even after successfully logging in via login.php).
Is there something wrong with this approach and how I am going about this?

Basically on page other than login.php I need a way to make sure user is logged in...

Comment: I think this solution is not clean. Because the other pages is really loaded and executed and the authentication is hard-coded in them. is there any other solution for really "denying access" to special pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to initialize Sessions in *every pages* you wanted to work with Sessions. Put **session_start()** at the top of the page (*before sending the header*).

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing [`session_start()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before checking or setting `$_SESSION['level']`?

Comment: I did that now but still the same problem. I'll edit the original post accordingly.

Comment: You're not calling session_start() before checking $_SESSION['level'] in the second script. That's what I mean by "checking or setting".